error TS2322: Type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any>' is not assignable to type
Today when I build the project, shows error:
> texhub-web@0.1.0 build
> tsc && vite build

src/redux/store/store.ts:7:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any, {}> | { readonly [$CombinedState]?: Reducer<undefined, any, never> | undefined; projShare: Reducer<...>; }'.
  Type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any, {}>'.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type 'CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }> | {} | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }> | undefined'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>'.
          Property 'projShare' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }'.

7     reducer: rootReducer,
      ~~~~~~~

  src/redux/reducer/combineReducer.ts:15:5
    15     projShare
           ~~~~~~~~~
    'projShare' is declared here.
  node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/index.d.ts:538:5
    538     reducer: Reducer<S, A, P> | ReducersMapObject<S, A, P>;
            ~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'reducer' which is declared here on type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, any, Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<CombinedState<{ projShare: { collar: any; }; }>, UnknownAction, undefined>]>, Tuple<...>, {}>'


Found 1 error in src/redux/store/store.ts:7

Now I am using "redux": "^4.2.1", this is the store.ts defined like:
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from '@/redux/reducer/combineReducer';

const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    // middleware: [thunk],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState
});

export default store;

and this is the root reducer defined like:
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import projShare from "@/redux/reducer/project/ProjectShareReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    projShare
});

export default rootReducer;

this is the project reducer defined like:
import { ProjCollarModel } from "@/model/proj/share/ProjCollarModel";
import { AppState } from "@/redux/types/AppState";

const initState: AppState["projShare"] = {
    collar: {} as ProjCollarModel[],
};

const ProjectShareReducer = (state = initState, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_COLLAR_USERS":
            return {
                ...state,
                collar: action.data
            };
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

export default ProjectShareReducer;

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have already tried to update the version to latest like this:
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit@latest @types/react-redux@latest

